# Plotting the graph of sin(1/x)

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I want  to plot graph without using **tikzpictures** .

I have tried this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math}
\title{Assignment}
\author{student}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.25,-4.25)(7.5,4.25)
\psset{xunit=3cm,yunit=3cm}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-1.25)(2.25,1.25)
\psplot[plotpoints=2500]{0.025}{2}{1 x div RadtoDeg sin}
\put(7,-0.5){$x$}
\put(-0.5,4){$y$}
\put(3,3){$y=\sin\frac{1}{x}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

But it is not running.

Edited part

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,border=12pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-plot}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-0.5,-1.25)(3.75,1.5)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-0.25,-1.25)(3.5,1.25)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
    \psplot[plotpoints=1000,linecolor=red]{0.025}{3}{sin(1/x)}
    \put(1.5,.75){$y=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$}
    \end{pspicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: edited.still it is not running .

Comment: I am using winedt10. I am not getting this option.

Comment: Actually this is my assignment problem. I am not familiar with TeXnicCenter. Although  I used **tikzpicture** in Winedt then it runs.

Comment: But i have to run it on winedt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-0.5,-1.25)(3.75,1.5)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-0.25,-1.25)(3.5,1.25)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\psplot[plotpoints=1000,linecolor=red]{0.025}{3}{sin(1/x)}
\put(1.5,.75){$y=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Having obtained the PDF output, you now ready to import it from within your presentation. Compile it with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The graph of $y=\sin\left(\tfrac{1}{x}\right)$}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics{yourgraphfilename}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Edit

You need to configure your editor to invoke the following batch file named `combo.bat`. It needs your input file without extension. Make sure you have 64-bit `ghostscript` installed on your machine. The path of `ghostscript` must be register in `PATH`.

```
rem this batch filename is combo.bat
rem %1 TeX input filename without extension

rem needs -t unknown
echo off

if exist "%~1.pdf" del "%~1.pdf"

if exist "%~1.tex" latex -shell-escape "%~1.tex"

if exist "%~1.dvi" dvips -t unknown "%~1.dvi"

if exist "%~1.ps" gswin64c -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o "%~1.pdf" "%~1.ps"

for %%x in (aux dvi log out ps toc nav snm) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")
```

Comment: I used but shows Undefined control sequence

Comment: I  am using Winedit 10

Comment: Are you compiling with `latex`, not `pdflatex`?

Comment: Personally, I do it via `xelatex`, and your edited part compiles normally.

Comment: Yes, but on my system, I have problems with `ps2pdf` and `dvipdf` and I don't have time to look into what happens.

Comment: By Xelatex it runs. Thanks

Comment: agree, I will. Thanks